# middle function

Tags: c++, string

I need a function middle that accepts a string and returns the middle character if there are an odd  number of characters and the two middle characters if there are a even number of characters in the string in C++ for a program I am writing unfortunately I cannot find anything pre-made for an example thats in c++

Comment: Try it out on paper, what is (length / 2)? what is the (length % 2)?

Comment: What should it do for the empty string?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
std::string middleCharacters(const std::string &str)
{
    if (str.length() <= 0) return ""; // For an empty string, return an empty string (customize this as desired)
    return str.substr((str.length() - 1) / 2, 2 - str.length() % 2);
}
```

For proof that this works: http://ideone.com/vId2l

Comment: If this was homework, just giving out the answer shouldn't be encouraged.

Comment: @XavierHo Yeah I agree, I kind of regret answering it now after the fact.